# Django, расширение модели User

Tags: python, django

Создал модель профиля, которая содержит дополнительные поля и связь "один к одному" с моделью `User`, но не получается их связать в контроллерах обоих приложений, ошибка атрибута:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'profile' for class 'User'

Проблемные места были подписаны комментариями в коде. Помогите правильно передать объект `profile` из одного контроллера в другой.

`signup/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
from profile.models import Profile


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            new_user.save()

            # При регистрации создаётся профиль модели Profile связанный с моделью User, вроде как работает:
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)

            return redirect('login')
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

`profile/views.py`

```
from .forms import UserEditForm, ProfileEditForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'profile/profile.html')


@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)

        # Ошибка атрибута вылазит здесь ниже (instance=request.user.profile)
        # Unresolved attribute reference 'profile' for class 'User'
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)



        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request,
                  'edit_profile/edit_profile.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form})
```

`profile/models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    inst = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    vk = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    fb = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user)
```

`profile/forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')


class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('city', 'date_of_birth', 'inst', 'vk', 'fb')
```

Comment: А где же собственно определение вашей модели?

Comment: модель рабочая, её нет смысла здесь писать, вся суть в передаче атрибута

Comment: Вся суть в том, что атрибут находится в модели и было бы очень неплохо, если бы Вы её всё же привели

Comment: так у модели `User` вряд ли есть атрибут `profile`

Comment: сюда в request.user.profile
 profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
нужно добавить сам profile из signup/views.py
profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)

вот и не знаю как его правильно импортировать